# MPI_Send getting stuck when executing with different nodes

Tags: ssh, mpi, google-compute-engine, send, recvmmsg

I have a very simple MPI program where node 0 sends a character to node 1, but the send and receive are getting stuck whenever I use two or more different machines. The program works fine when I use several processes in only one machine. It seems to be a communication problem, but I can't figure it out what it is.....

Here's the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int numtasks, rank, tag = 1;
    char inmsg, outmsg = 'x';

    MPI_Status stat;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    if ( rank == 0 ) {
        MPI_Send(&outmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, 1, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    else if ( rank == 1 ) {
        MPI_Recv(&inmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stat);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Also, here's some important notes:

1. I'm using a cluster of 2 Virtual Machines inside Google Compute Engine: **mpi-test-uaiw** and **mpi-test-130b**;
2. I have already configured the passwordless **ssh** between the two VMs, that is, from **mpi-test-uaiw** I can just type **ssh mpi-test-130b** and it works fine (the opposite also works);
3. The simple "Hello World" using MPI works with this cluster, but it does not contain any send or receive operations;
4. Firewall is deactivated.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem:

I was using MPICH and running my program with **mpirun**. The problem, from what it seems, is that mpich was using the wrong network interface. Each node has two interfaces: **lo** and **ens4**. From what I saw in other posts, it seems that **lo** is used for transferring data from one node to itself, while **ens4** is used to communicate with other nodes. I verified this using the following ping commands:

- **`$ ifconfig -a`**: shows the available interfaces;
- From mpi-test-uaiw:**`$ ping -I lo mpi-test-130b`**   -> FAILS
- From mpi-test-uaiw:**`$ ping -I ens4 mpi-test-130b`** -> SUCCESS
- From mpi-test-uaiw:**`$ ping -I lo mpi-test-uaiw`**   -> SUCCESS
- From mpi-test-uaiw:**`$ ping -I ens4 mpi-test-uaiw`** -> FAILS

One of the possible solutions is to use the **mpirun --mca btl_tcp_if_include ens4** to make sure mpirun uses the ens4 interface to communicate with the other node. But this didn't work for me, since MPICH doesn't recognize the **--mca** parameter. Therefore, I did the following:

1. Removed the packages I used to install MPICH (in both nodes): **`$ sudo apt-get remove libcr-dev mpich mpich-doc`**;
2. Installed the OpenMPI (in both nodes): **`$ sudo apt install openmpi-bin openmpi-doc libopenmpi-dev`**;

By installing the OpenMPI, my code worked. Hope it helps anyone who faces this same problem!